# Backbone - Save model changes to local object

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, architecture

I am building an app which will load a JSON file and use that to populate all models. I have to keep a list of changes and then post this back to the server after a 'publish' button is clicked.

I think a combination of using Backbone.LocalStorage and using model change events to then track which models have changes sounds right but it'd help to hear from someone who's gone down this route or solved similar!

Does this approach makes sense? Is there a better one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to track individual changes and not just the final state before saving, then it is probably a good idea to create an `Audit` model or something similar. You can hook into the `change` events as you suggested. Saving those `Audit` models to the server can be done using the standard version (or some batched modification) of `Backbone.sync` whenever you want. That model might look something like this:

```
var Audit = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults : {
    auditableType: "", auditableId: null, auditedChanges : ""
  },
  paramRoot : "audit"
});
var Audits = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model : Audit
});
```

Then create a Model prototype that all audited models can extend from:

```
var audits = new Audits();
var AuditedModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  initialize : function (options) {
    this.listenTo(this, "change", function (model, options) {
      audits.add({
        auditableType : this.paramRoot,
        auditableId : this.id,
        auditedChanges : this.changed
      });
    });
  }
});
```

Now just extend from your `AuditedModel` for any models you want to track changes on.

```
var User = AuditedModel.extend({
  paramRoot : "user",
  // Do whatever
});
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew. This makes alot of sense. I spoke with another part of my team and they let me know I can post back the entirety of the updated json i'll be using to create my models. I'm using localstorage so I will probably serialize those models to post back. I'll need to track changes as well to show a list in app before publishing so your solution sounds great. Thanks